# d3.js - adding zoom and pan prevents dragging nodes

Tags: d3.js, zooming

I've added zoom capabilities to my graph with the following code (snippets):

```
zoomed = () => {
    svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
};

zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([0.3, 1.5])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .call(zoom)
    .append('svg:g');
```

This works as expected.  I can zoom or pan the entire graph.  However, I can no longer effect the position of a node because any "click" triggers panning.

My dragging is defined as follows:

```
dragStart = function(d) {
    d.fixed = true;
};

drag = d3.drag()
    .on("dragstart", dragStart);

node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("width", function (d) { return d.width - 2 * pad; })
    .attr("height", function (d) { return d.height - 2 * pad; })
    .attr("rx", 5).attr("ry", 5)
    .call(drag);
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but my implementation aligns with all the examples I could find with similar functionality.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up disabling panning to make it work by disabling click events on zoom:

```
selection.call(zoom)
    .on("mousedown.zoom", null)
```